# Use minimum_should_match in elastic search query via java client

Tags: java, elasticsearch

looking all over, I couldn't find a way to include minimum_should_match param our match query when using the java client. we are running on elastic search 2.4.
this become a major need now in our system and reindexing/converting the field to not_analyzed is not an option since re-indexing our index takes few days now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so simple :)

[MatchQueryBuilder](https://static.javadoc.io/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/6.1.1/org/elasticsearch/index/query/MatchQueryBuilder.html#minimumShouldMatch--)

```
QueryBuilders.matchQuery(FIELD_NAME, valueToMatch).minimumShouldMatch("100%")
```

[Thanks to David](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/use-minimum-should-match-in-search-with-java-client/115244) :)